# Verify a digital signed document by fetching public key from local CA at the time of verification

Tags: windows-server-2012, digital-signature, certificate-authority

Is it possible for a user (say A) to verify a digitally signed (by user B) document without having public key of user B in local system and fetching key from the server (local CA) at the time of verification.
Both users' machine are part of domain.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question? Which specific document format and/or digital signature format do you have in mind?

Comment: No. I have windows server 2012 R2 with active directory and enterprise CA to generate certificate. As digital signature and its verification requires two certificate, private and public. So if there are too many users in domain then I need to install public certificate of all users in all the machines in domain. 
So is there some other way, like keeping all public certificate of server and any domain machine which wants to verify the digitally signed document can contact CA and check authenticity of document?

Comment: Most PKI-based signature formats already include the signer's certificate as part of the signature so that it could be verified offline. Are you sure the retrieval is even necessary in your case?

Comment: Yes, signature can be verified offline. It is not necessarily required. But curious to know if such thing is possible.  As verifying signature offline requires installing certificate in trusted certificate store.

Comment: No, it requires installing the *issuing CA* certificate in the store. Not the individual signers' certificates!

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. To verify the signature I had to install the user's public certificate in the machine. CA certificate contains CA's public key that can verify the signature performed by CA only.

Comment: Installing CA's certificate work with web server certificates not with digital signature.

Comment: No, it's exactly the same kind of CA and works the same way.

Comment: It didn't work in my system. CA certificate is there but still signature wasn't verified. But when I add user's public certificate, adobe was able to verify the signature.